# Android Studio, how to deal with adb error?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, adb

I think my issue has something to do with the adb. I searched a lot online and tried to shut it down about 4 different ways and nothing helps. I am using a Mac. Here is what the Run tab of Android Studio says when I run my app:

```
06/16 16:36:06: Launching app
$ adb push /Users/melloo/Desktop/UCI/Intro-to-Mobile-App-Development-with-
Android/A2-Antoniya.Puleva/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk 
/data/local/tmp/x40240.antoniya.puleva.a2
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/x40240.antoniya.puleva.a2"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/x40240.antoniya.puleva.a2
Success

$ adb shell am start -n 
"x40240.antoniya.puleva.a2/x40240.antoniya.puleva.a2.MainActivity" -a 
android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 2983 on device Nexus_5X_API_22 [emulator-5554]
Application terminated.
```

and my manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:launchMode="standard"
    >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="List O'Names">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".NameListActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name = "x40240.antoniya.puleva.intent.action.ACTION_VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you run the app? Does it crash? Any errors on Android Monitor tab?

Comment: Mateus, on the emulator I get a message that says: "The app has stopped", if I try to run it again it says that it keeps stopping. Android Monitor shows absolutely nothing.

Comment: Your app is crashing, that's usually due to an error in your code. It's very weird that Android Monitor shows nothing. It should show logs from your emulator, and an error with stack trace when you get that message. Can you double check that the filters in that tab are correct? Make sure your emulator and app are selected.

Comment: Here are the screenshots from the monitor:
http://imgur.com/XqYcU7J 
http://imgur.com/wkc9ztd
http://imgur.com/PspOHUw

Comment: On the 2nd picture, on the right side of "Regex", the filter selected is ...example.namedb, but it looks like you're trying to run ...puleva.a2, so the filter is incorrect. Change it to the correct app or to "Show only selected application". Then you should start to see some logs and an error should show up after you run your app.

Comment: Ok, this worked! Now I am getting this:

06-21 18:08:50.263 2942-2942/x40240.antoniya.puleva.a2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: x40240.antoniya.puleva.a2, PID: 2942
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{x40240.antoniya.puleva.a2/x40240.antoniya.puleva.a2.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead

Comment: When I do the changes, I get errors.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question, such as the pieces that interact with AdapterView.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar error using Android Studio 3.0 Canary 3. Try doing following things:

1. Update your Android Studio to the latest version (if you are using 3.0, Canary 4 just came out yesterday)
2. I see you are using Emulator with Lolipop (api 22), try creating new device with api 25 (Nougat)
3. Try doing some change in manifest (like adding empty line, the point is to just change the manifest file), then go Build->Clean project and to run it again.

Comment: Jan, I followed all the steps above and the same thing happens, this has been driving me crazy for the past 5 days and I have a project due.